# Problem with UITapGestureRecognizer for double tap

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, tap

I've two `UITapGestureRecognizer`: `singleTap` and `doubleTap` initialized with two different actions.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

When I run my app in simulator the single tap responds correctly but not the double tap ! When I double clicks nothings happens, I suppose iOS dose recognize the double tap because the action of single tap doesn't being called (due to `[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];`), but I can't understand why doesn't it do the action `handleDoubleTap`.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the single tap gesture recognizer?

Comment: Nop... I've just changed `setNumberOfTapsREquired` to 3 for doubleTap, and when I double click nothing happens neither ! It's stranger since in this case a double click should be recognized as a single click, right ? Double click issue with the iOS simulator perhaps ?

Comment: Never trust the simulator, I would test this on an actual device.

Comment: Try here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008975/how-to-tap-to-zoom-and-double-tap-to-zoom-out/9009554#9009554

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem is that `UIImageView` and `UILabel` both override the default value of `YES` for the `userInteractionEnabled` property, and sets it to `NO`.

Add `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` and try again.

Answer (score 6):

The following code works for me:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gr {
    NSLog(@"----------------- tap ----------------");
}
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gr {
    NSLog(@"================= double tap ============");
}
- (XXXView*)createXXXView {
    XXXView *view = [[[XXXView alloc] init] autorelease];
    view.xxx=...;//irrelevant

    UITapGestureRecognizer *dtr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    dtr.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

    UIGestureRecognizer *tr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];

    [tr requireGestureRecognizerToFail:dtr];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:tr];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:dtr];

    return view;
}
```