# How to tap to zoom and double tap to zoom out in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm developing an application to display a gallery of `UIImages` by using a `UIScrollView`, my question is, how to tap to `zoom` and double tap to `zoom` out, how does it work when handling with `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to implement UITapGestureRecognizer - docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/) - in your viewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];       

    // what object is going to handle the gesture when it gets recognised ?
    // the argument for tap is the gesture that caused this message to be sent
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapOnce = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapOnce:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapTwice = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapTwice:)];

    // set number of taps required
    tapOnce.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapTwice.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

    // stops tapOnce from overriding tapTwice
    [tapOnce requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapTwice];

    // now add the gesture recogniser to a view 
    // this will be the view that recognises the gesture  
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapOnce];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapTwice];

}
```

Basically this code is saying that when a `UITapGesture` is registered in `self.view` the method **tapOnce** or **tapTwice** will be called in `self` depending on if its a single or double tap. You therefore need to add these tap methods to your `UIViewController`:

```
- (void)tapOnce:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    //on a single  tap, call zoomToRect in UIScrollView
    [self.myScrollView zoomToRect:rectToZoomInTo animated:NO];
}
- (void)tapTwice:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    //on a double tap, call zoomToRect in UIScrollView
    [self.myScrollView zoomToRect:rectToZoomOutTo animated:NO];
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, i will test it and report back has soon has possible.

Comment: is it possible Webview recognize touch the links in side webview

Comment: [tapOnce requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapTwice]; is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.0** version that zooms twice on double tap.

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

Somewhere (usually in viewDidLoad):

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onDoubleTap(gestureRecognizer:)))
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

Handler:

```
@objc func onDoubleTap(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let scale = min(scrollView.zoomScale * 2, scrollView.maximumZoomScale)
    
    if scale != scrollView.zoomScale {
        let point = gestureRecognizer.location(in: imageView)

        let scrollSize = scrollView.frame.size
        let size = CGSize(width: scrollSize.width / scale,
                          height: scrollSize.height / scale)
        let origin = CGPoint(x: point.x - size.width / 2,
                             y: point.y - size.height / 2)
        scrollView.zoom(to:CGRect(origin: origin, size: size), animated: true)
        print(CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))
    }
}
```

Comment: This still works the same way in Swift 5/Xcode 12.4. To zoom out with another double tap (and an animation) you can simply add the following to the `else` part: `scrollView.setZoomScale(scrollView.minimumZoomScale, animated: true)`