# UIWebview Single tap & Double tap

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I created a iPhone project with webview. I have displayed the JS graph inside the webview. I need single tap to show the tooltip & double tap to link. How can I identify the single tap & double tap in UIWebview..

Comment: I think that could help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909807/does-uigesturerecognizer-work-on-a-uiwebview

Comment: I am using multiple webview & also creating a webview programatically based on links.

Comment: Try here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008975/how-to-tap-to-zoom-and-double-tap-to-zoom-out/9009554#9009554

Comment: is it possible Webview recognize touch the links in side webview