# UIScrollView double tap zoom not pinching

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming, scale, pinch

I'm able to zoom with a specific maxZoomScale with double tap on UIScrollView. After my UIScrollView has been zoomed I still can zoom on it with a pinch. I would like to block this zoom pinch. 
Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: How u have implemented zoom?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008975/how-to-tap-to-zoom-and-double-tap-to-zoom-out-in-ios/9009554#9009554

Answer (score 0):

you shouldnt be able to zoom more than your max scale, you are likely referring about the bouncingZoom... set that to NO then:

`bouncesZoom=NO;`