# How to make an image go fullscreen in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, fullscreen

I'm a newbie to xcode and objective c, and I'm wondering how to make an image go fullscreen on touch, using a tap gesture...
Can anyone help me?

Here's the code I've tried:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

-(void)handleTap{
imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);

}
```

Comment: check this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008975/how-to-tap-to-zoom-and-double-tap-to-zoom-out-with-uiscrollview

Comment: do not forget imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

Answer (score 0):

You can change the frame size of the imageview then it'l automatically go to full screen mode.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

-(void)handleTapGesture{
    imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);

}
```

Comment: I just get this error message:
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

Comment: wher you kept this code?

Comment: I put it beneath the ViewDidLoad [super viewDidLoad]

Comment: post your code in your question what ever you tried.

Comment: remove colon (:) in @selector(handleTap:) and try it.

Comment: Yeah, I just did that, and it worked, but the image doesn't go to fullscreen, it just gets a little bigger and some of it hides under the TabBar, and I want it to be like on Facebook, you know...

Answer (score 0):

This

```
// Detecting touches on your UIImageView
UITapGestureRecognizer *myImageViewTapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                               action:@selector(changeFrameOfMyImage)];

myImageViewTapped.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:myImageViewTapped];

//...
//...

-(void)changeFrameOfMyImage {
    myImageView.frame = self.view.frame;
}
```

will probably do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    -(void)handleTemplateTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
    {
         imageview.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Where am I gonna put what? And what am I gonna write in the .h file?