# how to double tap zoom and two fingure zoom uiimage in uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

hi i have actually multiple images in uiscrollview. actually i want to implement image scrolling like in iphone image gallary. am downloading images from url to imagearray then i can successfully display and scroll these images from imagearray in uiscrollview. but my problem is i want to enable double tap zoom in/out and two fingure zoom in/out in uiscrollviiew like in iphone gallary . like when user double tap an image will zoom in . and when user again double tap that image that image will zoom . and also same case with twofingur gesture. i tried to implement it reading tutorials but cant succeeded actually the problem is when i double tap an image doubletap image method called succcessfully but can do effect on image size this is the code which i have been implement for scrolling and gesture recognition 
for gesture recognition i used the code one from the apple site

```
    if (imagesArray.count < 1)
    {


        msgView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 190, 250, 40)];
        [msgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [msgView setAlpha:0.5];

        UILabel *mgtLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 8, 250, 25)];
        [mgtLbl setText:@"Sorry no image available for this post"];
        [mgtLbl setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0]];
        [mgtLbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [mgtLbl setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        [msgView addSubview:mgtLbl];
        [self.view addSubview:msgView];
    }
  else  {

      [msgView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    srcVw = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    srcVw.scrollEnabled = YES;
    srcVw.delegate = self;
    [srcVw setZoomScale:1.0];
    srcVw.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    srcVw.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    srcVw.pagingEnabled = NO;

    //add the scrollview to the view
    srcVw = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
    srcVw.pagingEnabled = YES;
    [srcVw setAlwaysBounceVertical:NO];
    //setup internal views
    NSInteger numberOfViews = imagesArray.count;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
        CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
        image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0,self.view.frame.size.width,400)];
        /*
        [image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.junkremoval.co.uk/bedspace/%@",[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i]]]];
        */
        image.image = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:i];

        image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
      //  image.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=image.image.size};




        [srcVw addSubview:image];

    }
    //set the scroll view content size
    srcVw.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width *numberOfViews,
                                   self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:srcVw];

    [image setTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];

    [image setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];


    // add gesture recognizers to the image view
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTwoFingerTap:)];

    [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [twoFingerTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];

    [image addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [image addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [image addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTap];




    // calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
    float minimumScale = [srcVw frame].size.width  / [image frame].size.width;
    [srcVw setMinimumZoomScale:minimumScale];
    [srcVw setZoomScale:minimumScale];


    }



/************************************** NOTE **************************************/
/* The following delegate method works around a known bug in zoomToRect:animated: */
/* In the next release after 3.0 this workaround will no longer be necessary      */
/**********************************************************************************/
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scale+0.01 animated:NO];
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scale animated:NO];
}

#pragma mark TapDetectingImageViewDelegate methods

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // single tap does nothing for now
}

- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // double tap zooms in
    float newScale = [srcVw zoomScale] * ZOOM_STEP;
    CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
    [srcVw zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}

- (void)handleTwoFingerTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // two-finger tap zooms out
    float newScale = [srcVw zoomScale] / ZOOM_STEP;
    CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
    [srcVw zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark Utility methods

- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {

    CGRect zoomRect;

    // the zoom rect is in the content view's coordinates.
    //    At a zoom scale of 1.0, it would be the size of the imageScrollView's bounds.
    //    As the zoom scale decreases, so more content is visible, the size of the rect grows.
    zoomRect.size.height = [srcVw frame].size.height / scale;
    zoomRect.size.width  = [srcVw frame].size.width  / scale;

    // choose an origin so as to get the right center.
    zoomRect.origin.x    = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width  / 2.0);
    zoomRect.origin.y    = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);

    return zoomRect;
}
```

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d49768/image-zooming-in-iphone/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008975/how-to-tap-to-zoom-and-double-tap-to-zoom-out-in-ios/9009554#9009554

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have all you need [here](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser)

Comment: Please read this meta post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: As others have said, you need to add the relevant parts otherwise this is not an acceptable answer.