# Implementing pinch/double tap to zoom for a UIImage

Tags: ios, ios7, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to workout how to implement a `UIImage` that has pinch/double tap to zoom. Is this possible with a standard `UIImageView`?

Looking at other questions at documentation it has to be completed with a `UIScrollView`?

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomingByTouch/ZoomingByTouch.html

The issue I see is that the above link suggests using `initWithImage` on the scrollView, but that is not available?

I am looking to implement an Image that is full screen (no larger), if the image is larger it should scale Aspect to Fit into the full screen. The user can then double tap or Pinch to zoom into the image. What is the correct approach for this?

Comment: If you read previous paragraph in the guide you will see that `initWithImage` is from "TapToZoom example in the ScrollViewSuite sample code project, in the TapDetectingImageView class, which is a subclass of UIImageView."

Comment: I could not find that sample code available, can you?

Comment: Intresting... I downloaded the code not long ago from the Apple site and now cannot find too. Looks like they removed it. You can try to look here at github https://github.com/darcyliu/SampleCode/tree/master/ScrollViewSuite

Comment: Great thanks, thought I was going mad

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008975/how-to-tap-to-zoom-and-double-tap-to-zoom-out-with-uiscrollview/9009554#9009554

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Never try to zoom an image itself - it consumes just *too much* time. Instead, as you've mentioned, zoom the view. It can be made with `UIScrollView` using almost default parameters.

Here is how: [How to zoom in/out an UIImage object when user pinches screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500027/how-to-zoom-in-out-an-uiimage-object-when-user-pinches-screen)